# sending userId by params vs extracting it from JWT token

Tags: rest, security, authentication, jwt

I want to discuss one thing.

Suppose, I have a POST API that is JWT authenticated, supposed I want userId in this API. Here I can think of two approaches

1. either send userId using the post body
2. extract it from the JWT token itself

Now the second approach makes more sense for some cases like a follower followee API

**but my main questions are:**

```
 1. is going with the extraction from JWT token approach, a significant step toward increasing security?
 2. Is there any cons to using this approach?
```

Comment: If you take it from the request body, what would keep me from sending whatever I want? Am I missing something in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to extract userid from jwt token and you'll get from as an example req.userDetails.userid if you set the req.userDetails where you handling token